# jad for blackberry non-midlet application

Tags: blackberry, native, java-me, jad

I am writing a regular application for Blackberry. I want to know, is there anything similiar to JAD for pure native blackberry application (no j2me) ? If JAD is applicable to regular BB app then please guide me to use JAD for it.

Answer (score 1):

The ALX file is probably the closest equivalent to a JAD.  ALX files define the elements of a BlackBerry application.  They are required for installing apps using the BlackBerry Desktop Manager. You can generate one using the BlackBerry JDE (Project -> Generate ALX).

Also, here's a link that defines the elements of an ALX file: [ALX Elements](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/7693/Elements_and_attributes_for_alx_files_513046_11.jsp).

Here's a link to the [BlackBerry Development Guide](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/7682/BlackBerry_Java_Development_Environment-4.7-US.pdf), which has a section on packing and distributing BB apps.

Finally, here's a link to a forum post about setting up a server for hosting BlackBerry apps for OTA download/install: [OTA Server](http://www.blackberryforums.com/general-legacy-device-discussion/6394-installing-themes-over-air-ota.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Basically I want to use it OTA, to be able install from online server. Is it possible to install using ALX like this ?

Comment: Add a link to a useful post on OTA server setup.